# How to install Joomla 2.5 component by copying the files without using the J install manager

Tags: php, joomla2.5, jcomponent

When installing custom component on a Joomla 2.5 everything works well. If I just copy and paste the content of the component in the appropriate folder `/components/com_mycomponent` without installing it the directory structure becomes the same but the component doesn't get found when requested.

I assume that installation is needed for a component to work. My question is how can I simulate this installation without actually installing the component. So how can I tell Joomla that there is a component copied in the components directory.

I need that to be able to create test components and develop them without actually installing them on the platform until they are ready.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select `Extensions` → `Extension Manager` from the drop-down menu of the `Joomla! Administrator Panel`. Then select the `Discover` menu item in the `Extension manager` screen that appears.

As it says in the Joomla docs manual: `Discover` searches the Joomla! installation directories for uninstalled extensions. Any uninstalled extensions found will be displayed in the extension listing. Caches the search results so they continue to be displayed on subsequent visits to this screen."

Here is the link to the actual [manual page](http://docs.joomla.org/Help16:Extensions_Extension_Manager_Discover#Toolbar).

Hope this helps.

Stoyan

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this for my projects 
   First, login to your Admin panel 
    Go to Extend Tab, then click on Extension Manager
    You will find Discover tab and the component you have copied in the list. just click on Install button at the top and it will work as you have install any component.